# SVNSERVE ldap groups

Tags: svn, ldap, sasl

I need to configure svnserve daemon to authenticate users using the ldap group. All my svn repositories are in a CentOS box. I performed the following steps:

1- Install libraries:

> ```
> yum install subversion cyrus-sasl cyrus-sasl-ldap cyrus-sasl-plain db4-utils
> ```

2- Edit the svnserve.conf inside of each repository to use sasl and to set the realm name as the ldap  group that can access to this repository.

> ```
> # Disable anonymous access to the repo
> anon-access = none
> # Let’s make sure that you are authenticated if you want to write in the repo itself
> auth-access = write
> realm = a_goup_dn
> # Tell Subversion to use SASL for the authentication mechanism
> use-sasl = true
> # Make sure that there is no encryption for the authentication mechanism
> min-encryption = 0
> ```

3- Edit the file /etc/sasl2/svn.conf to configure the svnserve sasl communication.

> ```
> ###################################################################
> # For CentOS /etc/sasl2/svn.conf
> # For other distro you may need to put the file here : /usr/lib/sasl2/svn.conf
> # For other distro the file may also be named subversion.conf instead of svn.conf
> # Symbolic link may be your friend here to figure out where does this file #need to be and it’s name.
> #
> # Password method, use the sasl authentication deamon.
> pwcheck_method: saslauthd
> #
> ## Auxiliary plugin, use ldap
> auxprop_plugin: ldap
> #
> ## Mechanism list, plain text only
> mech_list: PLAIN
> ldapdb_mech: PLAIN
> # EOF
> #########################################################
> ```

4- Edit the file /etc/saslauthd.conf to configure the sasl ldap communication. The most important here is that I am using the %r substitution in the ldap_group_dn field in order to force to the user to pertain to the correct ldap group defined in each svnserve.conf file.

> #
>
> ```
> #/etc/saslauthd.conf
> #
> # Your AD server adress
> #ldap_servers: ldap://192.168.123.68:10389
> ldap_servers: ldap://192.168.123.122
> #
> # I love default domain name, I just want to put the username part for #my authentication #not the whole user@domain.local
> #ldap_default_domain: intech.com
> #
> # Where are the users located in the AD?  If you haven’t change the default tree of your AD it should be under the Users OU.
> ldap_search_base: dc=sample,dc=com
> #
> # You need a user account to be able to make the authentication in the Active Directory, I suggest you create a user just for that!
> ldap_bind_dn: cn=manager,dc=sample,dc=com
>
> #
> # Of course there is a password associated with this user, put it here :
> ldap_bind_pw: ldapuser123
> #
> # Misc options for LDAP to make it work with Microsoft AD.  Nothing to change here, move along…
> ldap_deref: never
> ldap_restart: yes
> ldap_scope: sub
> ldap_use_sasl: no
> ldap_start_tls: no
> ldap_version: 3
> ldap_auth_method: bind
> ldap_filter: sAMAccountName=%u
> ldap_password_attr: userPassword
> ldap_timeout: 10
> ldap_cache_ttl: 30
> ldap_cache_mem: 32768
> ldap_group_dn: %r
> dap_group_match_method: filter
> ldap_group_filter: (uniqueMember=%D)
> ldap_group_attr:  uniqueMember
> #EOF
> #########################################################
> ```

This seems to work but I wonder if there is any negative consequence for using the realm name attribute  to communicate the ldap group.

Thanks in advance